# error while using scroll_to method of kivy inside Recyleview 'function' object has no attribute 'is_triggered'

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

error while using scroll_to method of kivy inside Recyleview the error i am getting is this

'function' object has no attribute 'is_triggered'

you can see in method on_touch_up in the class ScrolView with is created by inheriting the class of RecyleView the thing i supposed to do is to scroll the Recycleview to the another card.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView 
KV = '''
<Card>:
    size_hint_y:None
    height:root.height
    md_bg_color:.4,.6,.4,.8
                
MDScreen:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        spacing:dp(0)
        
        MDBoxLayout:
            id:coll
            size_hint_y:None
            height:dp(2)
        ScrolView:
            id:g            
            viewclass:"Card"
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                id:box
                spacing:dp(10)
                default_size: None, root.height-dp(40)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                
                
        
        
'''
class Card(MDCard):
    pass
    


class ScrolView(RecycleView):
    name=NumericProperty()
    scroll_moved=None
    

    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            touch.grab(self)            
        return super(ScrolView, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        
    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            self.scroll_moved=True          
        return super(ScrolView, self).on_touch_move(touch)
        
    def on_touch_up(self,touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            if self.scroll_moved:
                if touch.y>self.height//2:
                    try:
                        
                        self.scroll_to(MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids.box.children[0])
                        
                        MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids.box.children[0].md_bg_color=(1,0,0,1)
                    
                            
                        MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids.box.children[-1].md_bg_color=(0,0,1,1)
                            
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                self.scroll_moved=False                     
            touch.ungrab(self)
            
        return super(ScrolView, self).on_touch_up(touch)
    
    
        


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    
    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(4):
            self.root.ids.g.data.append({"md_bg_color":(.4,.5,.7,1),"name":i})

    
Example().run()
```

Comment: Most probably you can not use method `scroll_to` in `RecycleView` as each widget is recycled once out of viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps you should just set the `scroll_y` property of the `RecycleView` to 1 instead of calling `scroll_to()`.

But the problem you are encountering is because the `Layout` classes all have a `_trigger_layout` attribute which is a `ClockEvent` that is used to schedule layout updates. However, the `RecycleBoxLayout` removes that property, so you get that error when `RecycleView` tries to access it in the `scroll_to()` method. You can work around that by defining a custom `RecycleBoxLayout` that adds back in a replacement for the `_trigger_layout`, like this:

```
class MyRBL(RecycleBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyRBL, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._trigger_layout = self.FakeTrigger()

    class FakeTrigger:
        is_triggered = False
```

Then, in your `kv`, replace `RecycleBoxLayout` with `MyRBL`.